# Writing and reading a type value to/from file

Tags: c#, types, io

I need to be able to store a type value into a file, and read it back into a type value later. What's the best way to go about this?

```
Type type = typeof(SomeClass);
binaryWriter.Write?(type);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd store the [assembly-qualified name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), assuming the assembly will still be present later:

```
binaryWriter.Write(type.AssemblyQualifiedName);
...
string typeName = binaryReader.ReadString();
Type type = Type.GetType(typeName);
```

If you already know what assembly the type will be in, you could just use the [full name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.fullname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (i.e. namespace and type name, but not assembly). Then use [`Assembly.GetType(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0cd10tb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) later.

Comment: Are `AssemblyQualifiedName` and `Type.FullName` the same ?

Comment: @Selman22: No, because `AssemblyQualifiedName` includes the namespace and `FullName` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`BinaryFormatter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class:

```
Type t = typeof (SomeClass);

BinaryFormatter serializer = new BinaryFormatter();
using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(filePath))
{
    serializer.Serialize(stream, t);
}

var obj = (Type)serializer.Deserialize(File.OpenRead(filePath));
```